# What different Stack Exchange apps exist for iOS?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

How do you access apple.stackexchange.com from your iOS devices?

What apps do you use and what is good/bad about them?

Comment: Ooh - a meta question that's so meta it wraps back to be a good iOS usage question.

Comment: Could somebody point out the reasons why (other than use of APIs to potentially reduce network bandwidth) these would be superior to accessing the website through mobileSafari?

Comment: @StevenLu The layout will be optimized for usage on an iPhone for example rather than using a desktop website on a mobile device. And bandwidth reduce using an API of course.

Comment: @neoneye there is an official iOS StackExchange app now. Maybe the accepted answer should change.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update

Unfortunately, since Oct. 2022, [the mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/187824).

---

**Old Answer**

<s>We have now [the **official** Stack Exchange app](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/?cb=1) available on [the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723). Enjoy.</s>

Comment: Up voted via the official app just to add to the meta that is this whole question to begin with.

Comment: @IanC. Replied via the official *Android* app. :)

Comment: I wish it were still possible to *enjoy* using it in 2020 :-(

Comment: Is there any official app as of 2023?

Comment: @Adam_G: There isn't any, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

I currently use [SixToEight](http://sixtoeightapp.com/) by Adam Wright ([App Store Link](http://itunes.apple.com/app/six-to-eight/id384094708?ign-mpt=uo=5)).  It's missing push notifications right now but will eventually be included as a in app purchase.  For push notifications I'm using [Prowl](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prowl-growl-client/id320876271?mt=8) to forward Growl messages from [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-os-x).

Comment: Six To Eight no longer works, it was discontinued along with v1 of the SE API

Answer (score 3):

There are several different apps available for iOS.

### SOStacked ([on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2338/sostacked-stack-exchange-iphone-client), [on the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/sostacked/id427708024?mt=8))

This app allows you to browse all the Stack Exchange sites on your iOS device. SOStacked also has different color schemes for each of the sites if you are using iOS 5. It costs .99¢ in the App Store.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

### MyStacks ([on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2965/mystacks-stack-overflow-trilogy-iphone-app-free), [on the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mystacks/id360030953?mt=8)).

This app is currently only available for the trilogy sites ([Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [Super User](http://superuser.com), and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), but the developer has promised an update to include the other sites. One cool feature that I saw was that it saves articles that you have viewed, so you can read them later offline.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use Stackboard, a universal iOS SE client that I wrote with a habit for being shiny:

[image] [image]

[image]

It's live on the App Store [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackboard/id681476896?ls=1&mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

I’ve released a full native stack exchange client (it includes 380+ channels). Here is the App Store link: https://apps.apple.com/it/app/crew-for-exchange/id1547171709?l=en

[image]

Comment: Installed, noticed you want $10/yr for notifications, uninstalled!