# What different Stack Exchange apps are available for the iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, software-recommendation

I am looking for iOS apps for the Stack Exchange network that support the iPad. This is very similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12417/what-different-stack-exchange-apps-exist-for-ios/), but the difference is that I'm looking for apps that run on the iPad (not in 2x mode). What different apps exist for browsing the Stack Exchange network on the iPad?

Comment: Community wiki? One app per answer?

Comment: @IanC. The original intent was not a CW, but I shall talk to mods.

Comment: There's no need for CW at present. Hit us up on chat, as anyone can edit and this is unlikely to need reputation diversion

Comment: @bmike Ok. Got it. and I did post it in chat. :-)

Comment: *Please* leave a comment if you downvote. Downvotes dont really help unless you explain why you are downvoting.

Comment: You can also search on **[Stackapp.com](http://stackapps.com/search?q=ipad)**.

Comment: Ummmm - safari is the preferred app for accessing the stack exchange network. What would an app do to enhance things?

Comment: Push notifications would be the main thing @bmike

Comment: Edit that into the question or perhaps ask a follow on question asking what apps / services support notifications from SE.

Comment: IFTTT is actually a really good solution, and as far as I know (and maybe I'll ask again), there are no apps that support notifications :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used 2 for iPhone, and have eventually gone back to the Mobile View as it was considerably better than either:

[Six-to-Eight](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/six-to-eight/id384094708?mt=8): Free. Worked OK, but you can't actually log in, you can merely track yourself as a user without being able to actually *do* anything

[StackMate](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackmate/id455688984?mt=8): $.99. Looked great, but soon worked out that by Stack Exchange it actually meant just SO, and not the SE network - wasted dollar.

As for iPad, there are only 2 available that work on iPad:

- [Answers for Stack Exchange](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/answers-for-stack-exchange/id488577641?mt=8)
- [FullStack](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fullstack/id420859244?mt=8)

And they both suck (imho).

For a start, FullStack only supports the Trilogy sites and Ask Ubuntu, so not the whole network.  And while "Answers for" covers all sites, it shares a further letdown with Fullstack in that neither of them allow you to actually log in and do anything other than browse.  This (as per the comments) may be because the API calls do not allow posting, but there is no reason why an App developer cannot use the APIs where they are available, and also put in a normal HTML webview of the actual site to finish of the missing parts - using the API does not limit you to *only* using the API if you are writing an app.

The mobile web view is far superior in every respect unless you are looking for non interactive bedtime reading.  One noted problem with the mobile view is that Chat does not seem to recognise the fact that you are logged in, meaning that while transcripts are available, you cannot enter a room and participate.

In addition to the above, [a quick hunt about StackApps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=ios) yeilds the following results, which are either deprecated, or were never fully released and may be interesting to read up on.:

- [StackUp](https://stackapps.com/questions/1261/stack-up-for-ios-1-0-1)
- [Stack Reader](https://stackapps.com/questions/2622/stack-reader-for-ipad-call-for-beta-testers)
- [iStack](https://stackapps.com/questions/1547/istack-for-ipad)

If you are wanting a native iOS app for reasons such as getting push notifications, you can easily bodge up a system for allowing push notifications for your inbox to be sent to you iOS device.  You will need the following:

- An account with [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com/)
- An account with [Boxcar](http://boxcar.io/)
- Your Boxcar account linked into IFTTT
- A task within IFTTT that says IF RSS - New feed item from  apple.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/9495/responses (*change to your own user ID*) THEN Boxcar - Send a message to my inbox
- The Boxcar app downloaded and installed on your iOS device.

Then, whenever you get a notification (an answer to your question, a comment on your answer, a shout in Chat etc) in your SE global inbox, it will send you a message into Boxcar, that may look something approaching the following:

[image]

You can customise the wording in the notification,but I have stuck to the defaults in this example.  Note, that the IFTTT feed checks currently run every 15 minutes.

Comment: And chatting - I can't log in to chat through iPad even if logged in to apple.stackexchange.com. Cookie issue?

Comment: Yeah, me too, I was going to raise a Q about that.

Comment: Not being able to write on the StackExchange network is a limitation of the API.

Comment: @AdamEberbach Actually you can. I have.

Comment: @stuffe, you've listed StackMate as discontinued and also posted it's link on iTunes. It's seems contradictory??

Comment: Thanks, confusion arose because I started looking at iPad only apps, and it's an iPhone one which subsequently got "misplaced".  Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [George Edison](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1121/george-edison)'s [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com/) to access the SE network on your iPad. Of course, you could argue that it is not an "app" in the true sense, but rather a web-app, but it serves the purpose.

["FullStack"](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fullstack/id420859244?mt=8&ls=1#) is an app (proper this time!) that lets you browse SO/SU/SF and AskUbuntu sites only. Screenshot uploaded by the author:

[image]

Comment: No worries... I saw you (or someone else) upvoted and then removed it. I sense a very predatory environment here because of the contest and voting only being done in cliques. Can't say I'm thrilled to join...

Comment: I was me. Although Stack Mobile is a great solution, i did specifically ask for iOS apps. Once I get more answers, I shall re-upvote your answer. I want to encourage *iOS* apps, rather than web apps. Don't delete your answer though. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I made an iOS SE client. It's available on the App Store [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackboard/id681476896?ls=1&mt=8).

Some tempting screenshots:

[image]
[image]

It's for-pay, but I *might* be able to get you a promo code if you ping me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10232/stackboard-hq). Maybe.

Comment: Looks extremely promising! Since it isn't released yet, I can't accept it, but ping me here when it's officially released (and I'll probably buy a copy too :D )

Comment: @daviesgeek It's live.

Answer (score 1):

### Note: This requires ruby 1.9.x, Mac OS X ships with 1.8.7. So unless you're really big into it, this won't work.

This one is a little hackish, and I'm going to (eventually, someday) make it a little not so hackish. I promise.

Ever wanted to get notified of SE notifications? Going away from the computer for the weekend, but *really* want to make sure you don't miss anything "important"? Well, this is for you!

First, install and sign up for [Boxcar](http://boxcar.io/), if you haven't already. (and if you haven't, I highly recommend it! Works very nicely for notifications of all sorts - Twitter, email, Facebook, etc.)

Next, you'll need to [head over here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-inbox#id=1739&filter=default&site=apple&run=true) and do two things:

1. Change your user ID to whatever yours is. To find out what it is, take a look at the number in your profile URL:
   Mine is `http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1739/jrg`, so my user ID is `1739`.
2. Get an access token. Head over to [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-inbox#id=1739&filter=default&site=apple&run=true) and request one like below:

[image]

And then after you've gotten an access token, you can copy it and then paste it into the part where it says "FILL_ME_IN".

Now, you need to install two libraries - serel, and boxcar_api.

Run `sudo gem install serel boxcar_api` and then wait until they are installed.

Next, copy and paste [this file](https://gist.github.com/96bd45f3ce0190e0f768#file_notify_me.rb) into `notify_me.rb` (or whatever you want to call it). I'm going to assume its in `~/bin`. Before you save, change the "your_email@domain.com" part to whatever you used to sign up for boxcar.

Now, lets go and hop into cron.

Run `crontab -e` in a terminal, which will edit your crontab.

It should ask you which editor you want to use, I suggest using nano unless you know vim or emacs really well.

I'm going to assume you aren't that busy on the site, so we'll have it run every two hours.

Paste the following into the bottom of your crontab:

`0 */2 * * *  ~/bin/notify_me.rb`

And then you should be good to go.

Enjoy, and if you find bugs, feel free to send me an email:

`james@jamesrgifford.com`

<sub>Eventually, someday, somehow, I'll move this into its own proper project, rather than a crazy hax</sub>

#### Known bugs/issues:

- Only checks every 2 hours. If possible, I'll change it in the future to check every 20 minutes or so.
- Notifies you regardless of if you have a new inbox message or not. Again, not ideal.

Comment: There is a much easier way to achieve this with IFTTT and the RSS feed into Boxcar

Comment: @stuffe I haven't found an RSS feed for your inbox - are you sure?

Comment: s/your/my (need more characters to make it a comment)

Comment: I put a large addition into my answer explaining the process.  I currently use it, have done for several months.  The feed is difficult to see acknowledged on the site, I think I came across is in a question once by accident largely.

Comment: @stuffe That rss feed also does edits on your questions/answers - seems rather noisy. My solution only sends comments and things that show up in your global inbox.

Comment: It does, but it is also clever enough (or perhaps dumb enough) to only send ones that you genuinely haven't already seen, so if you are logged in and acknowledging them, then unless the timing is particularly poor it should not show up as a notification.  It's also dead easy to set up and doesn't require you to have a PC checking it for you, so the usual mix of less customisation but simple, or more customisations and more complex.  Both solutions work, pick which fits your profile.