# What does Apple want for the WWDC Scholarship application uploads?

Tags: xcode, file

I am trying to submit my app for the 2013 Student Scholarship - [form here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/students/scholarship/)  (Dev program needed).

However, I am confused about what it is, exactly, that they want: Here's a screenshot of the section of the form I'm concerned about:

[image]

### App File

For this, I seem to have several possible options - which is correct?

#### 1 - .app file

Found in Xcode at the bottom of the Navigator:

[image: Navigator]

I understand that I would right click and click 'Show in Finder' - then Zip it if I went this way.

Or...

#### 2 - Ad-Hoc Deployment

Found by archiving the app and choosing this option:

[image]

If I choose Ad-Hoc, I end up with an .ipa file - is this what Apple wants?:

[image: ad-hoc file]

---

### 'Xcode Project'

I'm confused here too:

#### 1: Just zip the entire project:

[image]

Or...

#### 'Export as Xcode Archive'

Found by going to the Organizer of an archived app:

[image]

Comment: I hope it all works out for you. +1 if you make it.

Comment: What did you end up uploading, if you don't mind telling us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Apple wants the people that apply to know how the Xcode tool chain works and have invested enough time to be able to submit a real app for review rather than being people that can fill out a web form to apply for a ticket.

Now, since you've found us and asked for help with lots of detail, I think you are very close to qualifying for a chance to win a ticket, but you might need to ask a second question staking out **one specific step** that *you don't quite get*.

That will entice someone who is an expert to help you over the one item you have identified as the single biggest obstacle. At that point, you are free to ask again with your next biggest obstacle, but as you have surmised, asking too much of an answerer by submitting a "wall of question" is generally frowned upon on Q&A sites. Your nice pictures do help ameliorate the large amount of text, but it still seems like a three part question (or more) to me as written.

Lots of detail does not imply lots of thinking. We can't do your thinking for you, but we can attempt to help if you've shown clearly what you think and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: Also - I'm answering this as a general case - don't feel like I'm talking down to you or any new programmer. I might make use of this text to add to the site FAQ on how to ask a good question or react to someone saying you have "too much detail". I hope this helps and let us know in chat if you apply successfully for a WWDC scholarship. I am envious of your opportunity as I missed the raffle and do not qualify as a full time student. :(

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone at Stack Exchange, I won a scholarship.

[image: line]

<sup>Line for keynote. A quarter of it.</sup>

They fed us quite well (Donuts and tasty bread things), and then they let us in. Then they fed us again.

Currently, I'm working on an iOS SE app using the knowledge I gained there. More info [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99130/44427).